# Hide mesh light source but keep the light it EMITS using EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I've made a mesh that has an emission shader and I'd like to hide the mesh but keep the light that it emits. Is it possible? I know it's possible in cycles. But I wish to know about EEVEE.

I've tried using the 'hide from render' ( in the outliner ) button but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a shader like this - This will exclude the object from visibility, but will allow the cast lights and shadows to operate. However, since you are using an emission object to cast your "light", you will need to bake the lighting from it using an Irradiance Volume, before it will show up in the render. Also - remember to set the Blend Mode to Aplha Clip.

[image: InvisibleEmmit]

[image: Irradiance]

To get the full effect, make sure to enable "bloom" in Render Properties.

[image: Bloom]

Comment: Alternatively you can Bake Indirect Light (as proposed) and after that disable the Mesh-Light object from rendering :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with a mesh, unless I'm doing something wrong?
[Inline Link] (https://imgur.com/pVWLMvl)

Comment: Did you bake the lighting? If so, how big is your irradiance volume?

Comment: Yes I baked indirect lighting.The irradiance volume is: [link] (https://i.imgur.com/CwgHyJp.png) Thanks

Comment: That's weird... I don't know what to tell you. All I did was make a scene with a plane and a cube. I gave the cube that shader and added an irradiance volume. All I did with the volume was to.increase the X, Y and  Z resolution to 12. Then I baked and that was the result I got. I'm not sure why it's not working on your end.

Comment: I don't know, it might be an extension that's conflicting. I'll try on a different computer. I'll accept your answer as it does clearly work just not on my system at the moment. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Hey no problem. I'll keep an eye on the question - if you try on a different system later, and it's still not working, let me know, and I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: Thanks also to vklidu. I did read about this yesterday and tried it but it didn't work but that must be because of something on my system causing a problem with baked indirect lighting.

Comment: I've found the problem, irradiance volumes don't work with 100% metallic materials. If I change the BSDF metallic slider to less than 100% it works but 0% metallic works the best.

Comment: What do you know... now I learned something too! Glad you found the problem - I'll remember this going forward.